# Why should i check channel isWritable() before write the data

Tags: java, nio

I am using a `ServerSocket` channel (NIO) on server side. My question is, what would happen if I don't check if the socketchannel is writable or not before writing data to client? I tested with a server program which worked fine without checking if the channel is ready.

```
public class SelectorExample {  
    public static void main (String [] args)
            throws IOException {
    // Get selector
    Selector selector = Selector.open();

    System.out.println("Selector open: " + selector.isOpen());

    // Get server socket channel and register with selector
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocket = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    //serverSocket.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
    InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5454);
    serverSocket.socket().bind(hostAddress,0);
    serverSocket.configureBlocking(false);
    int ops = serverSocket.validOps();
    SelectionKey selectKy = serverSocket.register(selector, ops, null);

    for (;;) {

       System.out.println("Waiting for select...");

        int noOfKeys = selector.select();         

        Set selectedKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
        Iterator iter = selectedKeys.iterator();

        while (iter.hasNext()) {

            SelectionKey ky = (SelectionKey)iter.next();

                ++count;
            if (ky.isAcceptable()) {
                // Accept the new client connection
                SocketChannel client = serverSocket.accept();
                client.configureBlocking(false);

                // Add the new connection to the selector
              client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);

               System.out.println("["+new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())+"]"+"Accepted new connection from client: " + client);

            }
            else if (ky.isReadable()) {                 
                // Read the data from client

                SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel) ky.channel();
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(2048);
                int i =client.read(buffer);
                String output = new String(buffer.array());                 
                    System.out.println("Message read from client: " + output);
                output =output.trim();
                output=output+"\r\n";                

                //*********write message here******
                byte[] a=output.getBytes();
                ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.wrap(a);
                 client.write(bb);                   

                  buffer.clear();
                 System.out.println("   Sent    Message ");
                if (i == -1) {                  
                    client.close();
                   System.out.println("Client messages are complete; close.");
                }

            } // end if (ky...)
            //countkey++;
            iter.remove();                  
        } // end while loop

    } // end for loop
}
```

}

Comment: I don not see a `isWriteable()` method neither in `ServerSocket`nor in `ServerSocketChannel`

Comment: it is in SelectionKey class

Comment: If the SocketChannel is in blocking mode, the call to write will always write all data but it may wait to do so. If the channel is in non-blocking mode, it will only write as much bytes as are available in the socket's output buffer.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Here all bytes are written into  bytebuffer and then write into socket channel.anyway all the data are going to be availble for write right???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why should I check channel `isWritable()` before write?

There's nothing that says you should.

> what would happen if I don't check if the socketchannel is writable or not before writing data to client?

You might get a zero-length write. You might get a short write.

In general you should just write whenever you have something to write, and only use OP_WRITE *if* you got a zero or short write. Any idea that you can't write until `isWritable()` is fallacious.

Comment: "You might get a zero-length write" and "You might get a short write" happen when read bytebuffer data and write into the  channel and there is no free memory or not enough of memory in internal buffer right?? or anyelse situation cause this??

Comment: It happens when the socket send buffer is full, which in turn happens when the receiver's socket receive buffer is full, which in turn happens if the sender is outrunning the receiver.